# Expo App keeps crashing on Android while trying to navigate

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have an expo managed app with a button on the screen, when the button is pressed several API calls are made to my backend and finally after the last API call depending on whether the Platform OS is ios or android i would like the app to navigate to a specific screen.

On IOS, everything is working accordingly.

On Android, the expo app crashes and closes before navigating to the next screen.

Here is my onButtonClick function:

```
const handlePayment=async()=>{
   setLoading(true);

    const sessionResponse = await paymentApi.paymentSession(
      selected,route.params.transaction.id,cvv
      );

      if(!sessionResponse.ok){
        setLoading(false)
        if(sessionResponse.data){
          Alert.alert(sessionResponse.data.error)
        }else{
          Alert.alert("Unexpected Error Occurred while creating session.")
        }
      }

      console.log('create and update session',sessionResponse)

      if(sessionResponse.data.session.updateStatus==='SUCCESS'){
    const initiateResponse = await paymentApi.initiateAuthentication(
      sessionResponse.data.session.id,route.params.transaction.id
      );

      if(!initiateResponse.ok){
        setLoading(false)
        if(initiateResponse.data){
          Alert.alert(initiateResponse.data.error)
        }else{
          Alert.alert("Unexpected Error Occurred while initiating authentication")
        }
      }

      console.log('Initiate Authentication',initiateResponse.data);
      
      if(initiateResponse.data.result==='SUCCESS'){
        setInitiateWebView(true);
        const redirectHTML=(initiateResponse.data.authentication.redirectHtml).replace(/\\/g, '');
        setInitiateWebViewUrl(redirectHTML);

        console.log('session id ', sessionResponse.data.session.id)

        const authenticateResponse = await paymentApi.authenticatePayer(
          sessionResponse.data.session.id,route.params.transaction.id
          );

          if(!authenticateResponse.ok){
            setLoading(false)
            if(Platform.OS !== 'ios'){
              clearInterval(myInterval)
            }
            Alert.alert("Unexpected Error Occurred","Please try again")
            
          }

          console.log('authenticate payer',authenticateResponse.data)

          const authenticationResponseData = authenticateResponse.data;

          console.log('authenticate payer authenticate data',authenticationResponseData.authentication);

          const payerInteraction = authenticationResponseData.authentication.payerInteraction;

if(authenticationResponseData.authentication['3ds2']){

  const status = authenticationResponseData.authentication['3ds2'].transactionStatus;

          if(payerInteraction==='REQUIRED'&&status==="C"){
            console.log("Challenge Flow")
            setAuthenticateWebViewUrl(authenticationResponseData.authentication.redirectHtml.replace(/\\/g, ''))
            
console.log('Auth webview url::::::',authenticationResponseData.authentication.redirectHtml.replace(/\\/g, '')) 
----> this is the last thing that appears on console before android app crashes
            
            if(Platform.OS==='ios'){
              setLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate(routes.PAYWITHTOKEN,{html:authenticationResponseData.authentication.redirectHtml.replace(/\\/g, '')})
            }else {
            setLoading(false);
            navigation.navigate(routes.PAYWITHTOKENANDROID)
            }
            
}
```

The other screen is just a blank screen. I have tried navigating to that screen somewhere else inside my app and its working. The problem is here.

Comment: 1. What is the error message ?
2. What’s the content of PAYWITHTOKENANDROID ?
3. Is the route PAYWITHTOKENANDROID defined ?

Comment: @MichaelBahl hi, No error message comes up, just the app crashes, the content of PAYWITHTOKENANDROID is just a black screen and yes the route is defined since it works when i use it outside the handlePayment function. The app only crashes when i try to navigate inside the handlePayment function on android, when i remove the navigation it works. I have tried many work arounds like setting state inside then using useEffect and it still crashes

Comment: Check the message from adb logcat

Comment: I am running on expo go on android device should i do it on AVD?

Comment: Android studio or cli logcat will show an a log message of what's going on even if you use physical device.

Comment: I am not familiar with Android Studio, do you mind helping me how to see the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Follow instructions for watch logcat:

1. Open android studio
2. 

[image]

Comment: My projects are on VSC not android studio

Comment: also, i am using expo not java

Comment: That doesn't matter, android devices in debug mode or emulators will log messages.

Comment: Hi again, which filter log output should i be looking at?

Comment: You should filter your app id